# Binding a combobox to a database table

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox in my application , and I want to bind my combobox itemsource to a column in a table in my defined database

suppose the follwoing :

my database is called (Clincs) and the table is (Doctors) and the column is (Names)
and I want my combobox to retreive its items from this table and to get modified everytime the database is modified

Regards .

Answer (score 0):

In XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1">
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Doctors}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

The code-behind:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }

 public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            Doctors = new ObservableCollection();

            LoadDoctors();
        }

        private void LoadDoctors()
        {
            Doctors.Clear();

            foreach (var doctor in DB.GetDoctors())
                Doctors.Add(doctor);
        }
```

Note that this does not address your requirement of automatically updating the collection when the table is modified, but hopefully this will get you started on the right track.